# How to aggregate text sentences into a group under a common name in the sentences

Tags: python, pandas, text, nlp, aggregate-functions

I have data like this

```
          Sentences
XYZ ABC Asset Management UK Limited
XYZ ABC BDDF - Informations et Etudes Comm...
XYZ ABC (Suisse) SA
XYZ ABC Comm Bank
XYZ ABC, Tokyo Branch
XYZ ABC Securities Services
XYZ ABC INVESTMENT PARTNERS BELGIUM
GIE XYZ ABC Assurance
XYZ ABC Energy Trading GP (f/k/a Fortis En...
TKB XYZ ABC Investment Partners
XYZ ABC LEASE GROUP FR
XYZ ABC
```

I want to aggregate them under the name "XYZ ABC" as all of them contain these two words and the word also occurs in the list of sentences (at the last).
Similarly like this, there are other names having 2 or more similar words, How do I aggregate them into something like this:

```
         sentences                            grouped under
XYZ ABC Asset Management UK Limited             XYZ ABC
XYZ ABC BDDF - Informations et Etudes Comm...   XYZ ABC
GIE XYZ ABC Assurance                           XYZ ABC
XYZ ABC Energy Trading GP (f/k/a Fortis En...   XYZ ABC
TKB XYZ ABC Investment Partners                 XYZ ABC
XYZ ABC LEASE GROUP FR                          XYZ ABC
XYZ ABC                                         XYZ ABC
.......
ABC DEFGH IJKL Americas                      ABC DEFGH IJKL
ABC DEFGH IJKL Investment Grade Bonds        ABC DEFGH IJKL
ABC DEFGH IJKL Reality Television Series     ABC DEFGH IJKL
ABC DEFGH IJKL Delhi Branch                  ABC DEFGH IJKL
ABC DEFGH IJKL Suiesssee KPL ONG Ltd         ABC DEFGH IJKL
ABC DEFGH IJKL                               ABC DEFGH IJKL
```

The condition should be that the grouped name should contain 2 or more words and has to be there in all the sentences as well as should be an individual sentence by itself (the last sentences in both the example above). I tried using cosine similarity and word2vec approach but was not successful. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Strictly speaking, your problem can have no solutions (e.g. if some sentence doesn't contain any bigrams that occur in other sentences), or multiple solutions (if there are several such bigrams to aggregate by). 
Anyway, I would try to solve it by creating a term-document matrix, where each term is a bigram (two consecutive words), treat it as a matrix of a bipartite graph, and run some graph partitioning algorithm on it.

Comment: If there is an exhaustive list of all the company names(any ngram), regex could be an option.